# Finding the first child of an XML Elem in Scala

Tags: xml, scala

So, I'm working on a project which can receive multiple types of XML requests.  The type of the request is determined by the first child of the root tag.  So you could get something like this:

```
<a>
  <b>
    foo
  </b>
</a>
```

or:

```
<a>
  <c>
    foo 
  </c>
</a>
```

And perform a certain operation on `foo`, based on whether the first child of `<a>` is `<b>` or `<c>`.  I can't figure out any simple way to determine the first child of .  I suppose I could do repetitive matching, first checking for `a \ 'b'` then `a \ 'c'`, etc.  But I need to handle a bunch of different request types, so this would get unwieldy quick.  `Elem.child` isn't helpful, it just returns a one-element list: the Element itself.

How can I get the first child of an Element, without knowing beforehand the name of the tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you could try something like:

```
val firstChildName = xml.child.collect{
  case el:Elem => el.label
}.headOption getOrElse ""
```

You will get the first element child's label if the root has one or else you will get an empty string

Answer (score 1):

You can extract on "_" to ignore the name of the first node, so this should work:

```
val firstChild = (theXML \ "_").head //can do headOption here and map if there's a possibility of no child existing
firstChild.label match {
   case "a" => someOp(firstChild.text)
   case "b" => someOtherOp(firstChild.text)
...
}
```

Comment: This works as well, thanks!  If only I could accept both answers!